# Broker could not satisfy the silent request, Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I recently updated Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.7.3 and It logged me out of Visual Studio, and I am unable to use source control (We use TFS).

after entering the credentials, it pops up a message saying:

> We could not add the account
> Broker could not satisfy the silent request

Note:
We're on a Amazon Workspace and Using Active Directory

tried resetting user settings, restarting visual studio and the machine

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A fix for me was authenticating outside visual studio embedded browser, go to
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts
And change embedded browser to System Web browser and try again.

Check Image below:

[Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn1Q6.png)